# Add to cart is slow due to shipping cost calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Add to cart is slow due to shipping cost calculation by DHL plugin.
We added the following lines of code to our theme function.php

```
/*
Remove recalculation of the shipping cost when Add-to-Cart. This prevents slow add-to-cart.
*/
function filter_need_shipping ($val) {
    $prevent_after_add = WC()->cart->prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart;
    return $val && !$prevent_after_add;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_need_shipping' );

function mark_cart_not_to_recalc ($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data) {
    WC()->cart->prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart = true;
}
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'mark_cart_not_to_recalc', 10, 6);
```

The Add to cart is fast now but the following worning shows up in the dashboard as long as WooCommerce Plugin is active.

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart" on null in /home/website/public_html/wp-content/themes/woodmart-child/functions.php on line 568
```

Your help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_need_shipping($val) {
    $prevent_after_add = (isset(WC()->cart->prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart)) ? true : false;
    return $val && !$prevent_after_add;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_need_shipping');

function mark_cart_not_to_recalc($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data) {
    WC()->cart->prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart = true;
}

add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'mark_cart_not_to_recalc', 10, 6);
```

You need to check the `prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart` object is set in order to disable the warning. It won't be set until you add one product to the cart. The `woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping` hook will be fired on every product page load